# Time series bar chart with dictionary dataframes - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to create a timeseries chart where I have dataframes that are nested. Originally my data was on the format:

```
PartId  Event
100     [{EventId: 1, EventTime: "2022-06-19T10:50:14.513"}, {EventId: 2, EventTime: "2022-07-19T10:50:14.513"}]
...
```

Example data:

```
[
  {
    "PartId": 1000,
    "Events": [
      {
        "Id": 25,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:33:15.807",
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:50:14.513",
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:50:23.007",
      },
      {
        "Id": 25,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:52:20.457",
      },
      {
        "Id": 11,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T12:30:33.79",
      },
      {
        "Id": 16,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T12:38:31.167",
      },
      {
        "Id": 21,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T13:03:29.953",
      },
      {
        "Id": 21,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T13:03:30.403",
      },
      {
        "Id": 15,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T13:57:29.753",
      },
      {
        "Id": 27,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-22T10:29:09.857",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "PartId": 1001,
    "Events": [
      {
        "Id": 25,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:33:15.817",
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:55:14.297",
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:55:22.917",
      },
      {
        "Id": 25,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T10:56:19.31",
      },
      {
        "Id": 11,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T12:30:14.417",
      },
      {
        "Id": 16,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T12:38:16.267",
      },
      {
        "Id": 21,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T13:03:31.477",
      },
      {
        "Id": 21,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T13:03:32.657",
      },
      {
        "Id": 15,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-19T14:01:34.473",
      },
      {
        "Id": 27,
        "EventTime": "2022-04-22T10:29:09.873",
      }
    ]
  }]
```

I want a time series chart that display the time between each Event corresponding to a PartId. So the Event bar should take up the whole axis until the next event occurs.
[image: Wanted chart]

I have tried to Group my data based on PartId:

```
def GetEventPartIddf(df, iterations=2):

    df_strip = df["Events", "PartId"]].copy()

    event_dict = {"PartId": [], "EventTime": []}
    for i in range(iterations):
        el = df_strip.loc[i, "Events"]
        partId = df_strip.loc[i,"PartId"]
        for x in el:
            eventTime = pd.to_datetime(x["EventTime"])
            event_dict["EventTime"].append(eventTime)
            event_dict["PartId"].append(partId)
    df_events = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(event_dict)
    partIdGrp = df_events.groupby(["PartId"])
    return df_events, partIdGrp
```

But I am not sure how to print this plot in matplotlib. I have tried to loop though the dataframe, but I can't make it work.

```
def plotStackedBar(df, partIdGroup):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 5))
    for partId, df_group in partIdGroup:
        event = []
        diffTime = []
        i = 0
        color = iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, 10)))
        for row_index, row in df_group.iterrows():
            eventTime = row['EventTime']
            if (len(event) != 0):
                lastEventTime = event[i-1]
                diff = (eventTime - lastEventTime).total_seconds() / 60
                diffTime.append(diff)
                print(diff)
                if (diff > 3000):
                    break
            i += 1
            event.append(eventTime)
            c = next(color)
            ax.barh(partId, diffTime, color=c)
        print(event)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input (not text, not image, but code to construct an example DataFrame)

Comment: I have updated with example data now @mozway

Comment: @AnneHøgdahlSkjærseth, I updated my answer with the final code. If it is what you are looking for, please consider accepting the answer. If there is anything missing, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Here is the full code to get what you are looking for. I am making use of [matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot.html).

The idea is to generate a dummy dataframe in a given frequency (e.g. one row every 1 minutes in this case). Then I create plotting data by appending each 1 minute time data in case the event was active during that time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([{'PartId': dic.get('PartId'), **event} for dic in data for event in dic.get('Events',[])])
df['EventTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime'])
df['NextEventTime'] = df.sort_values('EventTime').groupby('PartId').EventTime.shift(-1)
df['diff'] = df['NextEventTime'] - df['EventTime']
df['diff_hours'] = (df['diff']/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).astype(float)
df = df.dropna()

min_event_time = df.EventTime.min()
max_event_time = df.EventTime.max()
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
t = np.arange(min_event_time, max_event_time, timedelta(minutes=1)).astype(datetime)

plot_df = pd.DataFrame(t,columns=['Time'])

plot_data = tuple()
offsets = list()
colors = list()

for (partid, id), df_grouped in df.groupby(['PartId', 'Id']):
    data_for_id = []
    for j, df_row in df_grouped.iterrows():
        for i, row in plot_df.iterrows():
            if (row['Time'] >= df_row['EventTime']) & (row['Time'] <= df_row['NextEventTime']):
                data_for_id.append(row['Time'])
    if len(data_for_id) > 0:
        plot_data += (data_for_id,)
        offsets.append(partid)
        colors.append(f'C{id}')
        
plt.eventplot(positions=plot_data, orientation='horizontal', lineoffsets=offsets, linelengths=0.2, colors=colors, linestyles='solid')
plt.show()
```

This code assumes your input data is in the field `data`.

[image]